# IE11 drag and drop not calling correct function on ondragstart()

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I have been banging my head on the desk over this, I have tried several accepted or noted answers and have not been able to figure out why IE is being difficult when all other browsers work.

I have a drag and drop on my page, from one box to another. I have a js file that is loading and works until you start a drag on an element from one box to another.

In debug(inspector) I have an event breakpoints set as regular break points refused to catch the event and never got fired anyway...

When you step through the code during the event... it takes you to a function that isn't even called on this page... and then fails obviously due to the argument being invalid...

I don't know where the code is faulting, but I'm sure it's something stupid, and I cant share the whole of the js file with you as I have code in it that is property of the company I have included as much as I can.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="border rounded-left col avail-content" id="left">
    <div class="draggable" ondrop="drop(event);" ondragover="draggedOver(event);" id="avail">
        <ul id="available-content">
             <li draggable="true" id="1" ondragstart="dragStarted(event);" ondragleave="dragLeave(event);">test 1</li>
             <li draggable="true" id="2" ondragstart="dragStarted(event);" ondragleave="dragLeave(event);">test 2</li>
             <li draggable="true" id="3" ondragstart="dragStarted(event);" ondragleave="dragLeave(event);">test 3</li>
             <li draggable="true" id="4" ondragstart="dragStarted(event);" ondragleave="dragLeave(event);">test 4</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The javascript code for the drag events:

```
var dragging = null;

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.style['border-bottom'] !== '') {
        event.target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
        //event.target.parentNode.insertBefore(dragging, event.target.nextSibling);
        //event.target.insertBefore(dragging, event.target.nextSibling);
        $("#" + event.target.id).after(dragging);
        $('div#right li').appendTo('#selected-content');
        $('div#left li').appendTo('#available-content');
    } else {
        event.target.style['border-top'] = '';
        //event.target.parentNode.insertBefore(dragging, event.target);
        //event.target.insertBefore(dragging, event.target);
        $("#" + event.target.id).before(dragging);
        $('div#right li').prependTo('#selected-content');
        $('div#left li').prependTo('#available-content');
    }
    refreshOrder();
}

function dragStarted(event) {
    if ($('body.default-bg').hasClass('ie')) {
        dragging = event.target;
        event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', dragging);
    } else {
        dragging = event.target;
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', dragging);
    }
}

function draggedOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var bounding = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offset = bounding.y + (bounding.height / 2);
    if (event.target.tagName == "LI") {
        if (event.clientY - offset > 0) {
            event.target.style['border-bottom-color'] = 'blue';
            event.target.style['border-top'] = '';
            event.target.style['border-bottom'] = 'solid 3px blue';
        } else {
            event.target.style['border-top-color'] = 'blue';
            event.target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
            event.target.style['border-top'] = 'solid 3px blue';
        }
    } else {
        event.target.style['border-color'] = '';
        event.target.style['border-top'] = '';
        event.target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
    }
}

function draggedOverDiv(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var bounding = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offset = bounding.y + (bounding.height / 2);
    if (event.target.tagName == "LI") {
        if (event.clientY - offset > 0) {
            event.target.style['border-color'] = '';
            event.target.style['border-top'] = '';
            event.target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
        } else {
            event.target.style['border-color'] = '';
            event.target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
            event.target.style['border-top'] = '';
        }
    } else {
        event.target.style['border-color'] = '';
        event.target.style['border-top'] = '';
        event.target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
    }
}

function dragLeave(event) {
    event.target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
    event.target.style['border-top'] = '';
}
```

This is where IE calls to when the dragstart event breakpoint is stepped into, as well as when it isn't breakpointed. I dont know why it is doing it:

[image: here it is]

then errors here:
[image: errors here]

the console:

[image: console image]

And then nothing happens or the browser goes into debugging mode and its very difficult to see where the issue lays, I have to be compatible with IE11 and newer which is why I haven't said screw it...

Troubleshooting done in alt browsers (Works as expected):
Chrome 68+,
firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit),
Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 ; Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

**UPDATE!!! It works now! Working code below:**
Thanks to a very helpful comment I reworked my code a little and bam it started working ... had a few other bugs but they are now resolved :)

JS Code:

```
var dragging = null;
var usingIE = false;
function dragEventHandler(event) {
   var type = event.type;
   usingIE = Boolean($('body.default-bg').hasClass('ie'));
   switch (type) {
       case 'dragstart':
           dragStarted(event);
           break;
       case 'dragdrop':
           drop(event);
           break;
       case 'dragleave':
           dragLeave(event);
           break;
       default:
           console.log(type);
           return;
   }
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.style['border-bottom'] !== '') {
        event.target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
        if (usingIE) {
            var moved_element = $(event.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
            var moved_from = (event.target.id == "avail") ? "sele" : "avail";
            $(event.target.id).after(dragging);
            $('#' + moved_from + ' li#' + moved_element.id).remove();
        } else {
            $("#" + event.target.id).after(dragging);
        }
        $('div#right li').appendTo('#selected-content');
        $('div#left li').appendTo('#available-content');
    } else {
        event.target.style['border-top'] = '';
        if (usingIE) {
            var moved_element = $(event.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
            var moved_from = (event.target.id == "avail") ? "sele" : "avail";
            $("#" + event.target.id).before(dragging);
        } else {
            $("#" + event.target.id).before(dragging);
        }
        $('div#right li').prependTo('#selected-content');
        $('div#left li').prependTo('#available-content');
    }
    refreshOrder();
}

function refreshOrder() {
    $('#masterDocDemoView').remove();
    clearDraggedContent();
    clearContentViewArts();
    var artInMasterDoc = $('#selected-content').children("li").toArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < artInMasterDoc.length; i++) {
        try {
            var element = artInMasterDoc[i];
            addDraggedContent(element.id);
            var tempArt = getArticleById(element.id);
            addArtToMasterDoc(tempArt);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    if (masterDocContent.length > 0) {
        buildViewDisplay("#content-view-master-document", "#doc-title");
    }
}
```

Comment: `event.target` is not a string, passing it has 'text' data is a call to failure (and since IE doesn't support anything than this 'text' option, makes sense they throw.

Comment: @Kaiido so how can you drag elements in IE? seems like this is a severe handicap. and it seems to only be internet explorer, where Edge seems to be fine with it, I have added more code to try to get the event to to be tracked but now it fails somewhere else, but the same error... why does IE Debugger suck?!? (rhetorical)... 

What would you suggest i do with the element that I am trying to move?

Comment: Okay I have checked the code that you mentioned may be causing the issue, I think that you are right. `"[object HTMLLIElement]"` seems to return when i set the data using `event.dataTransfer.setData("text",event.target);` in the chrome dev tools, and the call `event.dataTransfer.getData("text");`...

Comment: @Kaiido -- Thank you for your advice, i Was able to get it working... and its due to you... Would you mind reposting your comment as an answer so that i can give you credit for the find?